# Why can one x value correspond to multiple y values when I use matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to draw a curve to represent its changing trend. Here are my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [3.0589998800678586e-07, 3.575999869553925e-07, 4.17199998992146e-07, 0.9999997019767761, 5.364000230656529e-07]
y = [1509, 108, 99, 88, 85]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.save("./frequency.png")
```

Here is the graph I get:
[picture that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sZAJ.png)

There are not any same values. I want to know where is the problem?

Comment: Its a scale issue, one of your `x` values is a million times bigger than the others. It might be better to use a [log scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/log_test.html) on your `x` axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To consolidate the comments, there are two problems here:

1. The `x` values are not sorted
2. The `x` values are very small, so on a scale of `0` to `1`, the very small `x` values all appear seeemingly at the same spot.

You can correct #1 by sorting the values:

```
x, y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda pair: pair[0]))
```

By zipping `x` and `y` together here for the sort, you are ensuring that all of the coordinate pairs remain the same, they are just ordered separately. You can correct #2 using

```
plt.xscale("log")
```

Altogether:

```
x, y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda pair: pair[0]))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
plt.savefig("frequency.png")
```

to get

[image: final graph]

**Note**: I actually had to remove `plt.show()` to get the saved figure to not appear blank.